# Remotely show the most recent tag reachable from a git commit

Tags: git-remote

I can use `git describe` to locally show the most recent tag on a local git repository that is reachable from a git commit. Using [procps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) as an instance, `git describe` returns this `v3.3.11-4-g99fa7f9` value (at the time of this writing). However, if I don't already have a local git repository, I can use

`git ls-remote --tags https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps.git | grep -v "\^" | cut -d/ -f3 | sort -Vu | tail -1`

to remotely do the same as `git describe --abbrev=0` that returns this `v3.3.11` value and not this `v3.3.11-4-g99fa7f9` value. So, is it possible to remotely show the most recent tag that is reachable from a git commit to return this  `v3.3.11-4-g99fa7f9` value instead of this `v3.3.11` value  (preferably with a single instruction sans external scripts)?